# Compressible fluid flow through a branched pipe junctions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

Backdrop: Designing a dust extraction system (LEV) with a branched junction.

What principles allow for the calculation of volume flow rate and pressure at the inlets if the volume flow rate and pressure is known at the outlet using a *compressible fluid*?

I am familiar with Continuity and [Bernoulli equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) using incompressible fluids but clearly in this state they are inadequate here.

Alternatively is anyone aware of simple approximations for such calculations?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer to the respective principles behind compressible fluid flow through a pipe still interests me, it transpires that one can treat air as *incompressible* at *speeds below the velocity of sound*.

As such continuity (mass conservation), momentum and Bernoulli equations are all applicable in this situation.

Comment: You also have to consider compressibility if the air is being forced through a narrow aperture under high pressure. Basically any time the pressure difference is a substantial fraction of one atmosphere. But in your case the flow will be incompressible, yes.

Comment: The subject you need to read up on is Gas Dynamics, and I would recommend Zuckrow & Hoffman as a great reference.